# How Can i write update statement in mysql with select query?

Tags: mysql

I want to update table1 by taking `max(date) and min(Date) from Table2` for only if `table1.status=100` and `table1.Todate='0000-00-00 00:00:00'`
same thing I am trying with following query but it is giving error in group by

```
update table1 s 
left join table2  t 
on s.stCode=t.tsTask 
set s.stActFrom= min(t.tsDate),s.stActTo=max(t.tsDate)
WHERE s.stActTo='0000-00-00 00:00:00' and s.stStatus=100 
group by t.`tsTask`
```

if i execute this query i am getting following error.
`#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'group by t.`tsTask`' at line 1`

Can any one tell me how i can write this update query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have tried the above answers. That is not given me the required answer. So i have got answer from the following query.

```
  update table1 s left join 
                   (
                    SELECT min( tsDate ) AS MinDates, max( tsDate ) AS MaxDates, tsTask
                    FROM table2   
                    group by `tsTask`
                   ) AS t ON s.stCode=t.tsTask 
  set s.stActFrom= t.MinDate,
  s.stActTo  = t.MaxDate      
  WHERE s.stActTo='0000-00-00 00:00:00' and s.stStatus=100
```

Answer (score 0):

```
update s
set s.stActFrom= t.MinDate,
    s.stActTo  = t.MaxDate
FROM table1 s left join 
                       (
                        SELECT MinDate = min(tsDate), MaxDate = max(tsDate)
                        FROM table2   
                        group by `tsTask`
                       ) AS t
WHERE s.stActTo='0000-00-00 00:00:00' and s.stStatus=100 
ON s.stCode=t.tsTask
```

Comment: I am edited your query and it is working fine. i will accept this answer.

Comment: @Raghuveera: STOP trying to edit the query given in an answer.  If another query worked better for you, edit your question and say "I ended up using such-and-such" and put the corrected query there.